# Why Explorer.exe connects to 95.101.34.74 (an ip belonging to Akamai Technologies)?

Tags: windows

Looking at resource monitor, i saw a strange thing: the process explorer.exe was connecting to the ip address of Akamai Technologies (95.101.34.74). Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

**Why does Explorer.exe connect to 95.101.34.74 (an IP belonging to Akamai Technologies)?**

[Akamai Technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) is a company providing a content delivery network. This network is used to cache content so allowing faster delivery.

It has a large network of servers distributed worldwide. Space on these servers is rented to many large companies, including Facebook, Twitter and Microsoft.

**As Akamai is used by Microsoft seeing connections from svchost / explorer / internet explorer to Akamai is quite normal**.

They can be seen during the following circumstances:

- During Windows update (which may be running in the
  background)
- When verifying digital signatures:

  - One of the responsibilities Explorer.exe has, is to verify the
    digital signature on signed software. To do so it will contact the
    signing authority, which may be Verisign, GoDaddy, Comodo etc, when a
    digitally signed application is launched. This also used a connection
    to Akamai.
- When browsing the internet:

  - When a user navigates to the URL of an Akamai customer, their browser
    is redirected to one of Akamai’s copies of this website.
  - Note Explorer can also launch browsing sessions (for example when entering a URL into the Address Bar).

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am confused. I think explorer.exe is the resource explorer (files, folders...): why the resource explorer needs to connect to a remote ip?

Comment: in my case none of these are true. I logged in to my computer and there it is Explorer.exe is trying to connect to `deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com` on port 80. trying to do so from firefox gave me a 5 byte long binary file with \x30030A0101 inside. btw I believe it is windows update that is responsible for downloading updates and not Explorer (as question is asking)